# Ubuntu upgrade 16.04.1 failed to start load kernel modules

Tags: boot, drivers, upgrade, kernel

I've tried to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to the 16.04.1 version and I've got an error saying

> Failed to start load kernel modules

Once I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open the command line, the screen turns black and at the top left corner appears:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS ROPE-PC tty1

ROPE-PC login:
```

Now, I have no idea what I have to type in there because Ubuntu previously only asked for my password...

Comment: Can you please turn of SECURE BOOT in your BIOS, and see if that fixes the problem for you? Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

The login prompt asks for your username.(**If you do not remember user name, see another shortcut further below**)When you must have installed Ubuntu 14.04, the installer automatically selects a PC name(that appears over a network) based on user name. ROPE-PC is the PC name. So, I guess your username must be ROPE or rope or something similar(I hope you remember). Please enter:

```
ROPE-PC login: (your user name here)
```

Then the terminal will prompt for password

```
password: (Enter password here, no dots will be displayed)
```

Then you will drop to ordinary prompt as:

```
username@ROPE-PC: $
```

From here, you can try finding out what went wrong with the kernel or try to reload the kernel(modprobe and modinfo utilities help)

I ran into a similar problem with graphics modules not loading in Ubuntu 14.04 two years back. A simple fix solved the issue.
I suggest if you can connect to internet via LAN cable, please do so. It is easiest to switch on Ethernet port using ifconfig utility from command line. See here :
[ifconfig command examples](http://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-command-examples/)

Then try :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If you are sure that the pc downloaded all updates properly and that the internet connection was never interrupted, simply run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Once the above command finishes:

```
sudo reboot
```

If you do not remember user name: You need to enter grub. Please follow instructions here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode
to drop to root shell.

Another method to drop to root shell is as follows(source www.botskool.com/geeks/how-recover-your-ubuntu-1004-password):

1. Press e at GRUB menu. e means edit
2. Find out line that contains "**ro quiet splash**" and move the cursor using arrow keys and go to that line, simply replace "**ro quiet splash**" with "**rw init=/bin/bash**" without double quotes and then use CTRL + X to boot the system.
3. Now your system will boot to root shell.

   It will simply look like:

   ```
   #
   ```

   Then run

   ```
   dpkg --configure -a
   ```

   (*sudo is not required*)